# Ember data override foreign key convention

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to load json data into the following model using findAll:

```
App.Territory = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    code: DS.attr('string'),
    regionId: DS.attr('string')
});
```

When the model is actually created, converting back to JSON shows that it has a reference for region_id, which is null, but nothing for regionId.  Does anyone know of a way to override this default convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determined that it was the keyForAttribute method on the RESTSerializer that was calling `Ember.String.decamelize(name)` which formated the key.  I was able to work around this by adding the line:

```
App.store.adapter.serializer.keyForAttributeName = function (type, name) {
  return name;
}
```